# Display variable sized circles outside of nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I wanted to display eigenvector value sized circles on the outside of nodes in my NetworkX circular layout graph. So far, I am able to display the circles ontop of each node; however, I wanted the circle on the outside of each node.

For the nodes on the left, the circle would be on the left of the node. For nodes on the right, circle on the right of the node. Nodes on the bottom, the circle would be under the node. Nodes on the top, the circle would be ontop of the node.

My code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a random graph
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(20, 0.2)

# Calculate centrality
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G)

# Create labels dict with fixed digit format
labels = {
    node: '{:.3f}'.format(centrality[node])
    for node in centrality
}

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,
        pos=pos,
        node_color='lightblue',
        labels=labels,
        with_labels=True)

for node, (x, y) in pos.items():
    rad = centrality[node] * 0.25
    circle = plt.Circle((x, y + rad), radius=rad, color='orange')
    plt.text(x - .012, y + rad, node, fontsize=16, weight="bold")
    ax.add_artist(circle)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a scalar to the x,y positions in your `pos` dict, you can multiply them by a scalar to make the negative values more negative and the positive values more positive which expands the radius of the circle that the nodes make. You can replace your for loop with this (note the inclusion of the `shift` variable that shifts the position of the nodes).

```
shift = 1.1 # multiplicative scalar to put the eigenvalue circles outside the original nodes

for node, (x, y) in pos.items():
    rad = centrality[node] * 0.25
    circle = plt.Circle((shift*x, shift*y), radius=rad, color='orange') # multiply shift by x and y
    plt.text(shift*x -.02, shift*y, node, fontsize=16, weight="bold") # multiply shift by x and y
    ax.add_artist(circle)
```

[image: resulting graph]

Two caveats, this won't make the nodes/eigenvalue circles touch, and this likely won't be a general solution for all graphs and eigenvalues, so you'll have to play around with the `shift` value to make sure the `plt.Circle`s aren't too close/far from your nodes.